What are some good places in scripture or other resources in trying to understand "listening to God" in our daily lives?
This is probably a loaded question but I'm happy to learn of what you'll bring to the table if you think of some good input regardless of how you interpret the question.
I've noticed an mostly 'unspoken' discrepancy between Christian communities which leads to substantial differences in outcomes regarding them living out their faith (I'm in USA mostly around protestant circles for reference but I wouldn't be surprised if this conversation happens (maybe implicitly as well) in other places)
I am trying to wrap my mind around this and so far have only heard 'lessons' regarding these things which assume the audience to know/believe something about their lives and God which is never fully fleshed out.
Recently I heard John Mark Comer say something like [It's about the switch from decision making to discernment, or full surrender]. This is just the most recent example of such an idea that I've heard.
Frequently I've heard teachers explain away over-analyzing things through this lens like "what t-shirt you wear, what to eat for lunch etc. is not important in the grand scheme" but I've yet to hear a rigorous system of understanding these things.
As an ideology it is captivating as one can believe themselves to be behaving under the direction of God and making personal 'sacrifices' in offering up the outcome of decision to God, 'neglecting their personal desires and honoring more holy ways of being'.
But this same ideology can inspire guilt, as one could ask themselves "am I listening for/to God well enough, and not doing my best as a Christian?". When they are potentially expecting something of themselves that isn't actually expected (or desired) of us by God.
So that's where I'm at, I'm familiar with Proverbs 3:5-6, John 10: 27-28 and probably some other relevant verses I'm forgetting now, but I believe these things in layman circles get misconstrued and I'm looking for ways to understand how to apply these things in my own life (and maybe hopefully clear up confusion regarding these teachings for others if they've suffered in similar bouts of confusion/guilt).
To steal a quote from Dallas Willard "I don't have the [characters] to explain everything I don't mean" by this question so I hope I've done a decent enough job. Let me know if you think edits would be helpful.
I imagine it possible some early church father has some highly fleshed out discussion about internally walking through these things, but maybe I'm looking towards the past with too much of an enchanted lens. I just don't know of how to search for this concept in few words.
Thanks!

A good question, but not one with any kind of pat answer.  God does not 'speak' to us in just one way nor do we discern it through one particular formula.  I think it was Augustine who said love God with all your heart and do whatever you want.  The obvious constraint is supposed to be that the more you love God the more what you want is what he wants.

Thanks Mike @MikeBorden! I'm still convinced there's gotta be SOME good, honest, not self-deceiving, not superstitious/unhealthy material out there somewhere regarding this. Even if it's just someone else complaining haha. Peace

Since the phrase 'listening to God' is not a scriptural phrase, I don't see how support can be gained for it within scripture. It is always a bad idea to start with words communicated in the religious world and then try to find support within the bible. It's best to read the bible itself and then live according to what the word of God, itself, expresses to us.

@ Nigel J - Dear sir, Hearing God (KJV) and Listening (NIV) are indeed admonitions  mentioned repeatedly in the Bible!  God is a talker from Genesis onward...and He expected people to Listen! From the prophet Isaiah alone we find this:  Isaiah 33:13,  34:1,  42:18, 44:1, 46:3,12,  48:1,12,16,  49:1,  51:1,4,7,21. In both O.T. and N.T. men of God---and ordinary disciples---heard from God. Do we really think God zipped his lip after the first century, and stopped communicating with His congregations? Millions of Believers would heartily disagree. A listening ear is so important

Important QuestionThis is a very important question because Christianity is a "personal, relational, vibrant Religion, that links man with the Almighty God in a loving relationship. Christianity is not a religion that worships an idol that cannot hear, on the one hand; nor a purely cerebral, academic/theological institution, on the other hand.  The Voice still rings out ; Come unto Me, all you who labor and are heavy laden, and I will give you rest...and fellowship...and purpose...and joy!

I have three thoughts.

Open your ears
Open your eyes
Employ all means of communication approved by God

The Lord taught me the secret behind the first.

He delivers the afflicted by their affliction and opens their ear
by adversity. (Job 36:15, ESV)

An indispensable aid to listening to God is suffering in faith. All people suffer, but only those who hold fast to God in faith will hear what he is saying to them through that suffering. I learned this lesson through a sign. In January 2005, I lost hearing in my left ear. After a month on steroids, no improvement. The doctor said I would likely not regain my hearing. I went to the waiting room and pulled out my Bible and a card that tells you which verses to read each day. The card said to read Exodus 4. These words were prophetic:

Then the Lord said to him, “Who has made man's mouth? Who makes him
mute, or deaf, or seeing, or blind? Is it not I, the Lord? Now
therefore go, and I will be with your mouth and teach you what you
shall speak.” (Exodus 4:11-12, ESV)

That is the only place in the Bible that says that God makes people deaf. Reading those words, I knew God was in the room with me and I was at peace. It was his will and I accepted it. I stopped praying for healing. Two days later, my natural hearing returned. In the years since, God has used other suffering to open my spiritual ears.
Consequently, I recommend the Book of Job as helpful in learning to hear God’s voice through - not in spite of - suffering. I found that every lawful means of communicating  with God (or him with us) is mentioned (sometimes subtly) in Job.
Once your ears begin to open, there is the matter of your eyes. We look at earthly things and find them desirable, like Eve. Our eyes must learn to be dazzled not by the glory of the fleeting treasures of this world, but by heavenly treasures. Matthew 6 is a good place to start this journey of searching for spiritual treasures, a fitting continuation of Job 28, which speaks of how people seek gold and gems but do not know the way to wisdom, God’s true treasure.
After my ear was healed, I searched the scriptures and other sources for a list of those heavenly treasures. After years of hunting, I had a list and it had a most precious treasure: the Glory of God.
Two sources helped me here. First, I was impressed and humbled by Moses:

For how shall it be known that I have found favor in your sight, I and
your people? Is it not in your going with us, so that we are distinct,
I and your people, from every other people on the face of the earth?”
And the Lord said to Moses, “This very thing that you have spoken I
will do, for you have found favor in my sight, and I know you by
name.” Moses said, “Please show me your glory.” And he said, “I will
make all my goodness pass before you and will proclaim before you my
name ‘The Lord.’ And I will be gracious to whom I will be gracious,
and will show mercy on whom I will show mercy. (Exodus 33:16-19, ESV)

I realized that Moses valued God’s glory more than all else, and I did not. A second help was The Weight of Glory by C.S. Lewis. That theologian also had trouble coming to grips with the value of God’s glory.
In response, knowing that I could not hunger for something I could not see, smell, taste or touch, I began to pray and fast one day a week. Each Monday for the next three years of my fast I prayed the same prayer, “Lord, show me your glory.”
After I completed my fast, the Lord answered my prayer. I “saw” nothing, but I began to see a clearer path through life, beginning with the peace of God entering me for several months in 2016. I lost my job. I had no savings and a family of five to care for. Days later my mom died. A month later my dad nearly died. Despite that I had the emotional strength to handle it all with grace, even taking my dad on a trip to visit family and see the city of his birth, New York, one last time. For once in my life, the most important things in life were the things I treasured. Then in the years since, God has showed me his glory by enabling me to understand the Bible much better. His word has since become the most precious thing in the world to me, just as it was for Job.
Besides prayer and fasting, I can recommend scripture memorization and meditation. About thirty years ago, I memorized the whole Sermon on the Mount. Powerful truths flowed from that text after I had been at it for a couple months. That exercise inspired my later search for spiritual treasures.
As per Job, we should also listen to wise elders. This can be by reading Christian books, talking to actual church elders, or mature friends. This is still listening to God.
Another area in which Job was faithful was sacrifice. Jesus said he desires mercy and not sacrifice. What this means is that God desires us to make sacrifices from an attitude of loving concern, showing that we value our neighbor’s wellbeing more than the stuff we are giving up. I will not name the sacrifices I have made, but I will say that the very clearest that I have ever heard God’s voice speaking into my life was after making a great sacrifice - and on that occasion it wasn’t money. You can not buy an audience with God, so reflect on your motives. I have also made sacrifices with wrong motives, so I know how hard this can be.
For a passage from a pure-hearted woman who sacrificed much, I recommend Hannah’s prayers in 1 Samuel 1-2.
Giving to the poor or any acts of charity is a form of speaking to God. In the Bible, sometimes God consumed the offering by fire! That was surely a way of “hearing” from God! God sometimes arranges matters surrounding our offering to speak to us. (My examples are too personal.)
Prayer comes in all shapes and sizes. One way God delights to speak to us selfish people is when we pray for others. I was cold and tired one December day, but before lying down, asked God if there was anything he wanted me to do. You want to hear from God? Try that prayer a lot! After napping for twenty minutes, I awoke, completely refreshed. Then I heard a voice in my head, “Help!” I said, “Help? Who needs help?” A name of a woman from church popped into my head. I called her on the phone, got her machine, and left a message that I was worried about her was praying for her. Days later she called. How did I know? The very minute I called she was at a friend’s house, bawling her eyes out to God, wondering if he could hear her. Wondering if he cared.  My prayer touched two people. My friend knew that God cared about her and I knew that I was able to hear from God.
The next means I will cover is dreams. Dreams are trouble. I have heard from God through dreams. I have also heard from the adversary. Much discernment is required. Absent that, dreams can torment, destabilize, and misdirect you as they did me. Rather than summarize, I point you to this essay:
https://paulchernoch.github.io/paulchernoch/dreams.html
(The Psalms and Isaiah and prayer with my pastor helped deliver me from nightmares.)
There are other means, but I will close with angels. I never had much interest in angels. Nobody I know has ever seen one except a friend who had a vision of Jesus, the angel of the Lord, who came to him in the hospital and healed him of blindness in an injured eye. Thus it was unusual when in the summer of 2022 I prayed, “Lord, I have never seen an angel, but if I am ever in a situation where the only way to save me is to send an angel, please send an angel.” On December 26, 2022, I fell through thin ice while skating and broke my arm. Erica Poitras of the Winchester Fire Department came out on the ice on a sledge and pulled me to safety. Some angels are holy angels, while some are God’s more ordinary messengers, for angel means messenger. The only time in my life that I was in a situation where I was near death and would not survive without someone coming to rescue me was that day. The only year I ever prayed such a prayer was that year. That woman was a message from God. May you receive such messages, too - without a steel plate and seven screws in your upper humerus, of course.

The Bible has a great deal to say about listening, but the main lesson lies in grasping why God will not listen to us! It logically follows that if we speak to God but he chooses not to listen to us, then he isn't going to speak to us.
I once had a book called "Listening to God" by a lady in the USA called Joyce, but I would never recommend it to anyone for she majored on humans (what they should do) in order to get a response from God who would then be expected to speak to them, personally.
Another book I had was called "God Has Spoken" and it offers better direction, for it shows that it is God's self-revelation that is truly personal. God is revealed to humanity in the person of Jesus Christ, and those who put faith in what God has revealed (as detailed in the Bible) become friends of God. That is why Abraham, who had obedient faith, was called God's friend, by God, and Abraham heard God on several occasions. Clearly, he listened attentively to God, shown by doing what God required of him.
We have all of that record of God's dealings with humanity in the Bible. And what he looked for in Abraham, he looks for in all his children. Yet one of the prophets of old warned God's people:

"Behold, the days come, saith the Lord God, that I will send a famine
in the land, not a famine of bread, nor a thirst for water, but of
hearing the words of the Lord; and they shall wander from sea to sea,
and from the north even to the east, they shall run to and fro and
seek the word of the Lord, and shall not find it." Amos 8:11-12 K.J.V.

Notice that God takes the initiative in preventing people from hearing what he says? They will be aware that they are not hearing God, and start to search frantically, all over, for a word from God, but there will be a famine for that. Is there not a famine today for hearing the word of God? Oh, plenty is said about God, with massive amounts of words in digital and printed format, and spoken from some pulpits. People soak all of that up, yet still they are spiritually famished, for they are not hearing God speak! They are listening to the words of men, looking to men to tell them what God is saying. Why don't they just pick up a Bible and start to read from themselves what God has already spoken? Or is that not good enough for them? Do they want a personal word, for their ears only?
When Jesus was on earth, he could 'hear' God by using the three ways of communication God has provided - prayer, worship, and his written, holy word. Thus he knew God's will for him, day by day, and did it. Even at age 12, Jesus showed an astonishing grasp of all three. If that is how Jesus was enabled to listen to God, should we hope to short-circuit that with more direct dealings with God? Or do we think, "I already pray, worship, and read the scriptures!" Ah, but Jesus did what the scriptures said, even though that meant dying on a cross of shame. He knew it was God's will for him to do that, and accepted God's will, being obedient even to death on a cross.
But if our Bible reading, prayers and worship are to seek satisfaction for ourselves in our lives, and not purely to bring glory to God, our ears will be blocked. If we focus on listening for something about ourselves, we will not hear what God has already said about living for his glory. Learn from 1 Kings chapter 19 how God spoke to Elijah, directing his life. The key for Elijah was in verse 12. Now compare what Jesus said to his followers and what was to govern their lives in Matthew 6:24-34. The key for them to be able to listen to God is in verse 33.
It's how we listen to what God has already spoken that will determine whether we hear that "still, small voice" of the Holy Spirit. Up till now, how much of what God has already spoken have you really heard, compared with how much of men's words you have been listening to? There's only once place where we will hear what God has already spoken. We have to go there, and not deviate from there.
EDIT  My Bible reading this morning was one that helps answer this question, so I add it as another place in scripture to search. The child Samuel ministered in God's temple in Shiloh but he "did not yet know the Lord, neither was the word of the Lord yet revealed unto him." Then the Lord took the initiative in calling Samuel, by name. When he responded, "Speak Lord, for your servant listens", God revealed matters which the child then had to relay to the old priest, Eli. Reflect please on how God may choose to speak directly without the hearer having sought for such a personal communication from God; also that once he gets the person's attention, that one has to listen, then do as instructed. That's the answer in a nutshell. Do read 1 Samuel 2:22 through to 3:21, that last verse saying how the Lord revealed himself to Samuel by his word.

Confident DiscipleshipOne of the distinguishing personal characteristics of Jesus while on earth was expressed by His statement: Whatever I see the Father do, I do. And throughout the book of John we see Jesus in constant communion and communication with the Father. He has left us a great example to emulate.
But the million dollar question is "how do we do that?" How can we be a faithful disciple who hears God and gets his daily directions from Him? And not just directions, but to just enjoy fellowship with the Father, For in His Presence are joys forevermore!
Dialogue with DeityFirst, we must be convinced that God likes to talk with His children. We expect the Father's heart of God to be felt on earth. We can expect that where He leads He proceeds like a Shepherd.
I wrote a book that listed and commented on every place where God spoke to man or man spoke to God in the Book of Genesis: DIALOGUE WITH DEITY. And it is evident from the very first chapters of the written, revealed Word that God actively communicates with His creation...and He wants to...and He expected us to, as well. God is a talker! As well as a good listener.
So today, how do we walk in intimate fellowship with God? And how can we hear His voice? If we can, there is no greater privilege we can have while on earth! Nothing compares to knowing God.
Several saints and theologians have written about this: J.I. Packer, Brother Lawrence, Hannah W. Smith, Andrew Murray, Earnest Gentile, etc. But from the Bible we can also glean helpful guidelines on knowing and communicating with God. We learn that an earnest seeking disciple can:

Realize that God makes certain passages of the Bible come alive and speak directly to our hearts. Sometimes this comes in meditation; other times He will bring a scripture into our minds at an appropriate time. The psalmist is continually meditating on His word, on His goodness, on His Law.
God speaks directly, audibly into our ears. The word of the Lord came to... was a prophetic introduction at times in the Bible.
God often speaks directly and clearly to us through another prophet. He audibly speaks God's message that is unmistakable. Often there is a deep, heart-felt witness in our spirit of the truthfulness of the word. This prophetic word may be an encouragement, direction, correction, or edification.
God speaks to us in visions and dreams, usually of on-coming events, or of some message He wants us to relay on to another. Not all disciples are accustomed to this venue, though.
God also speaks through the message of the pastor and his sermon. Often one's mind will be occupied with a thought, only to hear that same thought flow from the pastor's mouth Sunday morning!

Which ever way a disciple hears from God (on his part), a disciple must be communicative on his own part, as well. We enter His Presence by:

Worship and praise, or as the Psalmist wrote: I will enter His gates with thanksgiving in my heart, I will enter His courts with praise...

We come to God with a clean heart. Remember, a sinner God will not hear.

We come to God's Presence with serious diligence. The Psalmist wrote, As the deer pants for the waterbrook, so pants my soul after Thee... Or as the epistle stated, The effectual, fervent prayer of a righteous man avails much. Or as Jesus said, Blessed are those who hunger and thirst after righteousness, for they shall be filled!

The true disciple also approaches God with a heart of faith, an expectancy of persistence, Ask, Seek, Knock (And the Greek verb tense is the 'imperfect' which implies a 'continual' action.) One never gives up in communication (asking) in talking to God about anything...until He responds with "now, not now, or a never"...all in His wisdom and timing.

Above all, be filled with the Spirit! The Holy Spirit discerns the mind of God, and He communicates it to us. So it is vital that  disciple "keeps being filled with the Spirit." (Joel 2:28, Acts 1:8, 2:4, 4:31 continuous verbal tense in Greek) Jesus emphasized the importance of the Holy Spirit in a disciple's life: Mark 1:8, Luke 11:13, 12:2, John 7:38-9, 14:16-17, 26, 20:22.It is the through the Holy Spirit that the Charismatic Gifts are dispensed; and many of these deal with communicating the words of God to men. (1 Corinthians 12-14)

And in all communication, the disciple recognizes and communicates in a Father-son relationship. Not as an outsider, but as a member of the Family of God blood-washed and shown favor by a loving Father.


Moments of Silence If a person has a period when he does not hear from God along the way, the best thing to do is to just keep on doing what you are doing! A person doesn't have to be told every morning what to eat or what clothes to put on! Nor to continue ministering. Just keep on, and God will communicate a course correction if necessary. God can't lead a footstep that is standing still! AND God will speak words of encouragement when necessary...even when at most expectant times! God likes to surprise His children to keep life exciting. (Also, don't forget the Footsteps poem. God works in our lives even when we don't realize it.)
And remember when God isn't talking, the disciple can still express heartfelt communication to the Father because He also listens. (Think of a father or grandfather in a living room with children scattered around talking away on and on. The Father isn't saying much, but that doesn't mean He isn't listening...or seeing what's going on. The Father may interject a needed comment now and then...and then the words, "It's supper time now, get ready!")
ResourcesGordon D. Fee, PAUL, THE SPIRIT, AND THE PEOPLE OF GODJ.I. Packer, KNOWING GOD; KEEP IN STEP WITH THE SPIRITA.B. Simpson, THE HOLY SPIRITJoyce Meyer, FILLED WITH THE SPIRITErnest Gentile, AWAKEN THE DAWN; THE GLORIOUS DISTURBANCEDick Iverson, THE HOLY SPIRIT TODAYAndrew Murray, WITH CHRIST IN THE SCHOOL OF PRAYERBrother Lawrence, PRACTICING THE PRESENCE OF GODRaymond Grant, DIALOGUE WITH DEITY

Actually, there is much to be said within the Church traditions based on scripture and saints. These are however usually forgotten or ignored by the protestant circles. Indeed what you are asking about is a rather uncommon matter, but you are right to point out that many do not concern themselves with it.
I'm eastern orthodox, and we have actually got an answer for this. So here is my understanding of what you are trying to figure out.
There is a short answer at the bottom.

What you are basically describing without knowing the word for is called "Hesychia" or "stillness". Hesychia is the way in which we acquire spiritual knowledge of God. It is kind of like the opposite of what modern society thrusts upon us. Every where we go, there is so much noise, and it drowns out the inner stillness that we use to listen to God.
So what is hesychasm? In spoken language, by stillness people imply idleness, leisure, but in ascetic terminology it has a special meaning. Hesychia, stillness, is not a passive divesting of the mind after the pattern of eastern asceticism, but it is a fervency of spirit which brings changes in the heart. It begets intuitions and sensations that transfer man from one fullness to a greater and greater fullness of divine love. They fill his soul with His peace, ‘which passeth all understanding’ (Phil. 4:7), and which alone can be imparted as a still small breeze to those around him. Stillness is a tension of love, which is extreme, but also peaceful at the same time.

Hesychasts do not surrender to inactivity, but experience in silence
the most dynamic state that man’s spirit can bear, being strengthened
by the grace of the Holy Spirit. Their activity is a crucifixion, for
the mind of man after the fall is like unto a ball floating on the
water of the sea. If we try to push it under, we soon understand that
it will never remain at the bottom, but will always bounce back to the
surface. Likewise, man must exert great violence on himself for the
mind to remain in the heart.
The whole being of those who continue with patience in this activity
becomes spirit, for they do not allow their mind to wander even for
one second. Established in the furnace of the heart, the mind remains
immersed in the invocation of the Holy Name of the Almighty Jesus.
Although this is torture for the fallen and divided human nature, it
is also the one and only way for man to be healed and render to the
Lord the total love that he owes Him.
Hesychasm is the quintessence of the Orthodox ascetic tradition and
those who embrace it are a living miracle. Despising tortures and
death, the martyrs give their good testimony in one instant, shed
their blood and enter unhindered in the heavenly feast. The hesychasts
suffer for years the martyrdom of living on earth in a body with
senses and a soul that constantly drag them down and yet, overcoming
every natural law, they unceasingly stand in the presence of God. They
separate themselves from all, from every human consolation, while at
the same time being united with the whole Adam, bearing in their heart
not only his tragedy but also the blessedness of Heaven.

Archimandrite Zacharias Zacharou



There are texts regarding this that have been translated into 4 volumes of "The Philokalia" which is a translated compilation of texts from various saints who wrote about Prayer and the spiritual life.

In the useful Glossary provided at the back of each volume, and under the word “stillness,” we will find the following:  “STILLNESS (hesychia): from which are derived the words hesychasm and hesychast, used to denote the whole spiritual tradition represented in The Philokalia as well as the person who pursues this spiritual path it delineates; a state of inner tranquility or mental quietude and concentration which arises in conjunction with, and is deepened by, the practice of pure prayer and the guarding of the heart.  Not simply silence, but an attitude of listening to God and of openness towards Him” [The Philokalia, Volume 4, p. 434-435].


It usually appears superficially to be similar to meditation or mystical prayer of eastern religions like in Buddhism. Using specific body postures, deliberate breathing exercises... but ultimately the purpose is to acquire an inner stillness and ignore the senses, while at the same time focusing on God. (Usually the Jesus Prayer is repeated as well)
While the repetition of the Jesus Prayer might be compared with a mantra, to use the Jesus Prayer in such a fashion is to violate its purpose. One is never to treat it as a string of syllables for which the "surface" meaning is secondary. Likewise, hollow repetition is considered to be worthless (or even spiritually damaging) in the hesychast tradition.

St. Theophan the Recluse once related that body postures and breathing techniques were virtually forbidden in his youth, since, instead of gaining the Spirit of God, people succeeded only "in ruining their lungs.

Regardless of if the use of body postures are used or not. The entire practice. This is based on the Gospel of Matthew where Jesus said "go into your closet to pray", it is interpreted to mean withdraw inwards to pray.

Eastern Orthodoxy relies on the writings and homilies of church fathers as well as several Ecumenical councils, which align with scriptures.
Of note, Gregory Palamas defended Hesychasm against Barlaam of Calabria in multiple "Hesychast Synods" in Constantinople from 1341-1351. Barlaam was advocating for an intellectualist approach to prayer...

The Kondakion of Saint Gregory Palamas mentions that, as a hesychast, he stood before ‘the First Mind’. This is the definition of stillness: the unwavering and constant abiding in the Spirit of God. This occurs when the mind of man continuously and infallibly stands before God without wavering. The fallen mind is unrestrained. It can only be bridled when the heart is circumcised by the yearning of love for Christ, which does not allow it to forget the beloved Lord even for one instant.  (-Archimandrite Zacharias Zacharou referring to the quote 2 below in my answer from Metropolitan Kallistos Ware)

And of course St. John Climacus

Every word is preceded by thought. And the remembrance of death and sins precedes weeping and mourning.
Not every desire for death is good. Some, constantly sinning from force of habit, pray for death with humility. And some, who do not want to repent, invoke death out of despair. And some, out of self-esteem consider themselves dispassionate, and for a while have no fear of death. And some (if such can now be found), through the action of the Holy Spirit, ask for their departure.
Some inquire and wonder: “Why, when the remembrance of death is so beneficial to us, has God hidden from us the knowledge of the hour of death?” – not knowing that in this way God wonderfully accomplishes our salvation. For no one who foreknew his death would at once proceed to baptism or the monastic life; but everyone would spend all his days in iniquities, and only on the day of his death, would he approach baptism and repentance. From long habit, he would become confirmed in vice, and would remain utterly incorrigible.
And I cannot be silent about the story of Hesychius the Horebite. He passed his life in complete negligence, without paying the least attention to his soul. Then he became extremely ill, and for an hour he expired. And when he came to himself, he begged us all to leave him immediately. And he built up the door of his cell, and he stayed in it for twelve years without ever uttering a word to anyone, and without eating anything but bread and water. And, always remaining motionless, he was so rapt in spirit at what he had seen in his ecstasy, that he never changed this manner of life but was always as if out of his mind, and silently shed hot tears. But when he was about to die, we broke open the door and went in, and after many questions, this alone was all we heard from him: "Forgive me! No one who has acquired the remembrance of death will ever be able to sin." We were amazed to see that one who had before been so negligent was so suddenly transfigured by this blessed change and transformation. We reverently buried him in the cemetery near the fort, and after some days we looked for his holy relics, but did not find them. So by Hesychius's true and praiseworthy repentance, the Lord showed us that He accepts those who desire to amend, even after long negligence. (The Ladder of Divine Ascent: Step 6 - On Remembrance of Death)



To achieve silence: Metropolitan Kallistos Ware says that “this is of all things is the hardest and the most decisive in the art of prayer. Silence is not merely negative – a pause between words, a temporary cessation of speech – but, properly understood, it is highly positive: an attitude of attentive alertness of vigilance, and above all listening. The hesychast, the person who has attained hesychia, inner stillness or silence, is par excellence, the one who listens. He listens to the voice of prayer in his own heart, and he understands that this voice is not his own but that of Another speaking within him.” (Emphasis added, Another as in God)



Psalm 46:10 “Be still and know that I am God.”
If you spend a few minutes every day praying The Jesus Prayer, we will be more involved in the lives of those around us.
Saint Seraphim of Sarov says “acquire inner peace and thousands around you will find salvation.”  (Verse and quote combined by Rev. Fr. Apostolos Georgiafentis)



The Church fathers resembled life to a glass of blurred water. If we agitate it, it remains blurry, but if we leave it still, the dirt will settle on the bottom, and the water will become clear. This is also what happens with man. In order to know himself, he needs to remain still. More often than not, people cannot see themselves as they are, neither can they discern their thoughts. It is only when they find stillness and concentrate in one thought, the thought of prayer, that ‘the secrets of the heart’ (Psalm 44:21) come to the surface. (-Archimandrite Zacharias Zacharou)


Conclusion?
Now obviously... not all are monastics or ascetics. But we can all practice several minutes of Hesychia each morning during our normal morning prayers. Even just 5-10 minutes of calmly praying in stillness, allowing God to speak to us from inside our Prayer.
I have heavily referenced Archimandrite Zacharias Zacharou, here is an article where you can read his words directly. (https://myocn.net/the-tension-of-hesychia-stillness/) This linked article has 35 sources, of which 30 of them are direct scripture)

Short Answer: I believe that you are describing without the right "characters" or "words" the concept of "Hesychia" an Inner Stillness that allows us to truly listen to God.
Peace be with you

Thanks-- I do believe we're speaking the same concept, maybe at different angles though, I'm directly referencing the intention/outcome of this practice of Hesychia if I understand correctly-- In some of these protestant circles It is common for people to speak implicitly as if the intended 'experience' of Hesychia (if i understand) is happening arbitrarily often in day2day and often the burden of participation that decides the frequency/depth in this interaction is placed on the human. Literature regarding/mapping out that is what I'm interested in. I hope to read of your article soon. Thanks
